# How to get fields values from an email using in Inbound Services in Email services

Tags: apex, inboundservices

I have created a InboundEmail service class for creating a contact. **By using this class i can able to get only last name of contact and inserting record successfully with last name**.

Class which i created:

```
global class createContact implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {

        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

        List<contact> memb = new List<contact>();

        try {
            contact mem = new contact();
            mem.Lastname = email.PlainTextBody;
            memb.add(mem);
            insert memb;
            System.debug('New member: ' + memb);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Error is: ' + e);
        }
        result.success = true;
        return result;
    }
}
```

**But i want to get more fields like first name, email, phone and some more.**

To get these fields i have to sent an email with body contains like last name, first name, Email and phone like the following image shows.

[image]

For Example:

If i send an email to salesforce which contains body like

```
Firstname: starone
Lastname : startwo
Phone: 123456789
Email : t.ravi@gmail.com
Description : salesforce
```

then a contact has to create with `first name is starone`, `last name is startwo`, `email is t.ravi@gmail.com` and `phone is 123456789` and `Description is salesforce`

How do i get these fileds in InboundEmail apex class(`createContact`)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way I see to do it:

- First, split your email body by lines using: `String[] bodySplitted = email.PlainTextBody.split('\n');`
- After that you will have an array filled with each line of your email body
- Then, if we assume that you will always have the values in the same order and this separator between your labels and your values: `': '` like `Firstname: starone`
- for each line of your new array, you will have to substring the right side after the `': '` separator like this: `String firstName = bodySplitted[0].substringAfter(': ');`

  - Then instanciate your contact fields with these variables like this: `contact.FirstName = firstName;`
- Finally, do this for all of your fields by changing the index of the array `bodySplitted`

> Please note that this solution is a bit tricky. It will not work if there is no line breaks between the fields of your email, if there is no ': ' separator between the labels and the values and if the order of the fields is changed.

Comment: could you please check this?
`String[] bodySplitted = email.PlainTextBody.split('\n');String firstName = bodySplitted[0].substringAfter(': ');
String LastName = bodySplitted[1].substringAfter(': ');
 String conEmail = bodySplitted[2].substringAfter(': ');
  String phone = bodySplitted[3].substringAfter(': ');
           String Description = bodySplitted[4].substringAfter(': ');
            mem.FirstName = firstName;
            mem.LastName = LastName;
            mem.email = conEmail;
            mem.phone = phone;
            mem.Description = Description;`

Comment: This should do the trick. If the `String[] bodySplitted = email.PlainTextBody.split('\n');` line doesn't work. You should try: `String[] bodySplitted = email.PlainTextBody.split('\r\n');` Sometimes line breaks use these characters.

Comment: I am unable to get this even i tried with both `\n and \r\n`. 
could please provide a piece of code?

Comment: @MartinLezer can we change into plain text body as Htmlbody of Email, if we change like that we can split easily That way is correct

Comment: @Vanisree You have all the code needed. Just try to debug it. What did you get exactly by running this?

Comment: @user36188 What do you mean?

Comment: we can translate the plaintextemail into Html body for that we can use <html>  tags for spliiting the values it could be easy,is that way correct way?

Comment: @MartinLezer, Just i have checked in debug Showing DMLException: Missing required field. I understood the exception But i am sending email with body like 
`firstName = raja
LastName = sekar
conEmail = one@gmail.com
phone = 123456
Description = got sucess`

Comment: @user36188 Yes you're right we could it with html too. But I think it will be also laborious.

Comment: Yeah @MartinLezer, Sorry. its my mistake. Now i got it and result too. 
Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help.